# why does ionic back button just displays menu icon?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a back button on the toolbar. However instead of getting an arrow to indicate to go back, I get a hamburger menu icon that does not do anything. Any way of fixing this issue?

I am using the latest ionic framework version

here is my code:

```
 <ion-toolbar color="success">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/login"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Register</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: Did you import the correct lib's? Maybe other styles override it?

Comment: yes pretty sure i imported the correct lib

Comment: found the issue - i was missing the ion-header outer container